# ¿como uno estas listas que estan dentro de una lista?

Tags: lista

Tengo esta lista, la cual tiene 3 listas adentro y necesito que todo sea una gran lista para poder leer cada numero con un for, ¿como puedo hacerlo?
[[9.0, 2.0, 7.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0], [3.0, 5.0, 29.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [5.0, 18.0, 4.0, 4.0, 8.0, 4.0]]

Answer (score 0):

No viene un lenguaje en especial, pero te paso la idea base:

```
     var arr = [[9.0, 2.0, 7.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0], [3.0, 5.0, 29.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [5.0, 18.0, 4.0, 4.0, 8.0, 4.0]];
     var nuevo = [];
     for(var i in arr){
       for(var j in arr[i])
       {
         nuevo.push(arr[i][j])
       }
     }
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es python, se me olvido especificar eso

Answer (score 0):

d = [[9.0, 2.0, 7.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0], [3.0, 5.0, 29.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [5.0, 18.0, 4.0, 4.0, 8.0, 4.0]]

for x in d[0]:
    final.append(x)
for x in d[1]:
    final.append(x)
for x in d[2]:
    final.append(x)
de esta manera lo logre mas facil